# How do i pass the on click event through a view?

Tags: android

So I have 3 views, one big one on top of the other two. The one on top is transparent. I want to be able to register an `onTouch` event on the views behind the big one on top, while the big one does nothing.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using [`onInterceptTouchEvent(TouchEvent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) from `ViewGroup`.  The documentation there is pretty clear on how you can achieve what you are after here.  You will likely want to `extend` your transparent parent (unless it is already an extension that you wrote) and override this method to do your bidding.