# Android view touch event

Tags: android, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i pass the on click event through a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786549/how-do-i-pass-the-on-click-event-through-a-view)

How to sent an touch event to the view under this view witch get the event

use "android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS this??

Comment: No downvote. [Please put some efforts in question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) so that you will get some good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use intents if you are changing activities and you are touching a button.

Comment: I do not want to changing activities.There are two views,one under the other one.How to sent event to the below one.Sometimes the top one should intercept the event,sometimes not

Comment: So if a user touches a button you want something to show if he does not something else? if this is the case you could edit your xml with android:visibility="invisible" or android:visibility="visible" and change it via java in you activity